# Change location of div when element is shown

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I’m having 3 titles with a button underneath to show more info about the subject.

I made a script to show/hide div on the button click. When I’m on a small device the div shows underneath the subject (just like I want) as you can see here:

[This is correct on small devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXHwT.png)

But when I’m on a desktop and the subjects are next to each other the div that shows pushes the other subject to the bottom.

I would like to have the show div to be underneath the 3 subjects.

This is wrong:

[This is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7J6d.png)

[How they all sould be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ3ve.png)

Anny idea on how to do this?

Also, is the a way to only show one div at the time, so when I open a new div, the previous one should close.

HTML:

```
 <!-- TOP 3 SERVICES -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-12 text-center mt-5">
            <img src="images/index/tijd.png" alt="time" class="mb-5 img-fluid">
            <h2>Always on time</h2>
            <button class="btn mybtn mt-2" onclick="showInfo('tijd')">See more</button>
        </div>

        <div class="service-detail mt-5 service-detail" id="tijd">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 text-center">
                <h1 class="mt-5"><img src="images/index/tijd.png" alt="" class="mr-5">Always on time</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                    labore
                    et dolore magna aliqua consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                <button class="btn mybtn mt-2 col-12 col-md-4" onclick="showInfo('tijd')">See less</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-12 text-center mt-5">
            <img src="images/index/trust.png" alt="trust" class="mb-5 img-fluid">
            <h2>Trust</h2>
            <button class="btn mybtn mt-2" onclick="showInfo('trust')">See more</button>
        </div>

        <div class="service-detail mt-5 service-detail" id="trust">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 text-center">
                <h1 class="mt-5"><img src="images/index/trust.png" alt="" class="mr-5">Trust</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                    labore
                    et dolore magna aliqua consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                <button class="btn mybtn mt-2 col-12 col-md-4" onclick="showInfo('trust')">See less</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-12 text-center mt-5 mb-5">
            <img src="images/index/24.png" alt="24/7" class="mb-5 img-fluid">
            <h2>24/7 support</h2>
            <button class="btn mybtn mt-2" onclick="showInfo('24')">See more</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="service-detail mt-5 service-detail" id="24">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 text-center">
            <h1 class="pt-5"><img src="images/index/24.png" alt="" class="mr-5">24/7 support</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                labore
                et dolore magna aliqua consectetur adipiscing elit.
                <br>
                <br>
                Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <button class="btn mybtn mt-2 col-12 col-md-4" onclick="showInfo('24')">See less</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function showInfo(id) {
  var a = document.getElementById(id);
  if (a.style.display === "block") {
    a.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    a.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: You should have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and post less code. Less code = more answers.

Comment: What do you mean by the last question? Do you want only one of the divs to show at a time, hiding the others? Or are you talking about "closing" as in  the divs overlapping and hiding the content under "see more"?

Comment: @ThomasDarvik, hiding the other, only showing one at the time

Answer (score 1):

put div with class "service-detail" inside col-md-4

Use bootstrap accordion for closing previous div, on opening of new one

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_accordion&stacked=h

Comment: Update link, 404 page cannot be found.

Comment: try this
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_accordion&stacked=h

Answer (score 0):

The following code does not require any additional JavaScript because it does the job with native Bootstrap 4 classes alone and I believe it does what you want. (you might want to fix a few minor things but in general, that should be it):

```html
<!-- TOP 3 SERVICES -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="myAccordion" data-children=".item">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 text-center mt-5 order-1 order-md-1">
            <img src="images/index/tijd.png" alt="time" class="mb-5 img-fluid">
            <h2>Always on time</h2>
            <button class="btn mybtn mt-2 mb-2 mb-md-5" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#myAccordion" data-target="#panel1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panel1">See more</button>
        </div><!-- col -->

        <div class="item order-2 order-md-4"><!-- order-2 moves this div to 2nd position on small screens i.e. underneath the previous -->
            <div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 text-center collapse service-detail mt-5" id="panel1"><!-- for toggle functionality this column needs to be wrapped in a div with the .item class -->
                <h1 class="mt-5"><img src="images/index/tijd.png" alt="" class="mr-5">Always on time</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    <br>
                    <br> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                <!--                <button class="btn mybtn mt-2 col-12 col-md-4" onclick="showInfo('tijd')">See less</button>-->
            </div><!-- col -->
        </div><!-- item -->

        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 text-center mt-5 mt-md-5 order-3 order-md-2"><!-- order-3 is what makes it show in the desired order on smaller screens; order-md-2 means it's gonna come in second place on medium screens -->
            <img src="images/index/trust.png" alt="trust" class="mb-5 img-fluid">
            <h2>Trust</h2>
            <button class="btn mybtn mt-2 mb-2 mb-md-5" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#myAccordion" data-target="#panel2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panel2">See more</button>
        </div><!-- col -->

        <div class="item order-4 order-md-5"><!-- order-4 moves this div to 4th position on small screens i.e. underneath the previous -->
            <div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 text-center collapse service-detail mt-5" id="panel2"><!-- for toggle functionality this column needs to be wrapped in a div with the .item class -->
                <h1 class="mt-5"><img src="images/index/trust.png" alt="" class="mr-5">Trust</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    <br>
                    <br> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                <!--                <button class="btn mybtn mt-2 col-12 col-md-4" onclick="showInfo('trust')">See less</button>-->
            </div><!-- col -->
        </div><!-- item -->

        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 text-center mt-5 order-5 order-md-3"><!-- order-5 is what makes it show in the desired order on smaller screens; order-md-3 means it's gonna come in 3rd place on medium screens -->
            <img src="images/index/24.png" alt="24/7" class="mb-5 img-fluid">
            <h2>24/7 support</h2>
            <button class="btn mybtn mt-2 mb-2 mb-md-5" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#myAccordion" data-target="#panel3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panel3">See more</button>
        </div><!-- col -->

        <div class="item order-6"><!-- order-6 is still necessary here because otherwise this div would show on top of all others -->
            <div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 text-center collapse service-detail mt-5" id="panel3"><!-- for toggle functionality this column needs to be wrapped in a div with the .item class -->
                <h1 class="pt-5"><img src="images/index/24.png" alt="" class="mr-5">24/7 support</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    <br>
                    <br> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                <!--                <button class="btn mybtn mt-2 col-12 col-md-4" onclick="showInfo('24')">See less</button>-->
            </div><!-- col -->
        </div><!-- item -->

    </div><!-- .row #myAccordion -->
</div><!-- container -->
```

For further customization you should study the documentation on this page:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about thad bootstrap class.

Comment: I have just updated my code snippet, check it out. It now works exactly as you'd expect it. Everything is done with native Bootstrap classes alone (no additional JavaScript required) and everything is fully responsive. The responsiveness is achieved with the order classes which allow moving divs around based on screen size. Read the comments in the code to better understand what's going on.

Comment: Did you try my updated code? Does it work the way you want? Consider marking my answer as correct if it does.

Answer (score 0):

*You are using bootstrap grid system.
The div was not divided properly
I have just included all the "service detail" class in 'col-md-4'*

**This is the correct code:-**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-12 text-center mt-5">
        <img src="images/index/tijd.png" alt="time" class="mb-5 img-fluid">
        <h2>Always on time</h2>
        <button class="btn mybtn mt-2" onclick="showInfo('tijd')">See more</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="service-detail mt-5 service-detail" id="tijd">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 text-center">
            <h1 class="mt-5"><img src="images/index/tijd.png" alt="" class="mr-5">Always on time</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                labore
                et dolore magna aliqua consectetur adipiscing elit.
                <br>
                <br>
                Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <button class="btn mybtn mt-2 col-12 col-md-4" onclick="showInfo('tijd')">See less</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-12 text-center mt-5">
        <img src="images/index/trust.png" alt="trust" class="mb-5 img-fluid">
        <h2>Trust</h2>
        <button class="btn mybtn mt-2" onclick="showInfo('trust')">See more</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="service-detail mt-5 service-detail" id="trust">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 text-center">
            <h1 class="mt-5"><img src="images/index/trust.png" alt="" class="mr-5">Trust</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                labore
                et dolore magna aliqua consectetur adipiscing elit.
                <br>
                <br>
                Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <button class="btn mybtn mt-2 col-12 col-md-4" onclick="showInfo('trust')">See less</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-12 text-center mt-5 mb-5">
        <img src="images/index/24.png" alt="24/7" class="mb-5 img-fluid">
        <h2>24/7 support</h2>
        <button class="btn mybtn mt-2" onclick="showInfo('24')">See more</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="service-detail mt-5 service-detail" id="24">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 text-center">
        <h1 class="pt-5"><img src="images/index/24.png" alt="" class="mr-5">24/7 support</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
            labore
            et dolore magna aliqua consectetur adipiscing elit.
            <br>
            <br>
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <button class="btn mybtn mt-2 col-12 col-md-4" onclick="showInfo('24')">See less</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```